# Cannot save value for field type 'interval' with Doctrine for Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine, intervals

I am using Symfony and Doctrine to try and save a DateInterval for a field (called `duration`) of type `interval`.

I am getting the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO workout_sessions (id, location, start_time, end_time, duration, created_at, updated_at, user_id, workout_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [14, \"home\", \"2019-01-23 08:27:00\", \"2019-01-23 09:45:00\", \"-P00Y00M00DT01H18M00S\", \"2019-01-23 09:04:41\", null, 10, 8]:\n\nSQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: \"-P00Y00M00DT01H18M00S\""
```

My code is as follows:

```
public function setDuration(): self
    {
        if ($this->endTime) {
            $interval = $this->endTime->diff($this->startTime);

            $this->duration = $interval;
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

In the above, `endTime` and `startTime` are both PHP DateTime objects.

The problem is that when Doctrine converts the DateInterval (created by the `$this->endTime->diff($this->startTime)`) it prepends the Postgres interval with a `+` or a `-`.

When I remove the plus or minus from the start of the string and add the value manually, it works. However, when I leave it on, Postgres will not accept the value.

Does anyone know a way to tell Doctrine to remove the prepended symbol?

**Edit**

The version of Dbal I am using is **2.5**

Comment: have you checked [Doctrine's type mapping doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/types.html#dateinterval) and [Doctrine's known vendor issues for Postgres](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/known-vendor-issues.html#datetime-datetimetz-and-time-types)?

Comment: I have, but there is nothing about my issue in there. Surely I can't be the only person? Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you sorted out this issue?